# self.minimum_height not working for BoxLayout containing other layouts

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a simple task list with a checkbox in the left and a text input in the right. I tried putting 20 checkboxes and text input inside a box layout, which I put inside a ScrollView. However, it seems that the minimum_height of the boxlayout does not involve the height of the two gridlayouts inside it. Any idea aside from setting the height of the scrollview to "xdp" so that in the future when the user adds another tasks, the height will adjust accordingly?

Python File:

```
class Task_List(GridLayout):
    pass


class CheckBox_Area(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.padding = (dp(10), dp(10), dp(20), dp(20))
        for i in range(0, 20):
            size = dp(40)
            check_box = CheckBox(size_hint=(1, None), size=(0, size))
            self.add_widget(check_box)

class List_Area(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "lr-tb"
        self.padding = (dp(10), dp(10), dp(20), dp(20))
        for i in range(0, 20):
            text = TextInput(text=str(f"Task {i}"), size_hint=(1, None), size=(0, dp(40)))
            self.add_widget(text)
```

kv file:

```
Task_List:

<Task_List>:
    rows: 3
    Label:
        text: "Tasks for Today"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
    Label:
        text: "Area for Quotes"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
    Scroll_Body:

<CheckBox_Area>:
    cols: 1

<List_Area>:
    cols: 1

<Main_Body@BoxLayout>:
    CheckBox_Area:
        size_hint: .1, 1
    List_Area:

<Scroll_Body@ScrollView>:
    Main_Body:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
```